# Calculate the 3-month change difference % by each group in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I had a dataframe like below, and have 3 months difference from June to March. Now I would like to calculate the change percentage, e.g. for A, the change% = -30/130 = -23%.

```
ID       Month       Amount     3-month Diff
A     2019-06-01      100         -30
B     2019-06-01       60         -10
C     2019-06-01      120          20
D     2019-06-01      100         NULL
A     2019-05-01       90         NULL
B     2019-05-01      100         NULL
C     2019-05-01      110         NULL
A     2019-04-01       80         NULL
B     2019-04-01       90         NULL
C     2019-04-01      100         NULL
A     2019-03-01      130         NULL
B     2019-03-01       70         NULL
C     2019-03-01      100         NULL
```

The expected output would like:

```
ID       Month       Amount     3-month Diff     3-month Diff%
A     2019-06-01      100         -30              -23%
B     2019-06-01       60         -10              -14%
C     2019-06-01      120          20               20%
D     2019-06-01      100         NULL             NULL
A     2019-05-01       90         NULL             NULL
B     2019-05-01      100         NULL             NULL
C     2019-05-01      110         NULL             NULL
A     2019-04-01       80         NULL             NULL
B     2019-04-01       90         NULL             NULL
C     2019-04-01      100         NULL             NULL
A     2019-03-01      130         NULL             NULL
B     2019-03-01       70         NULL             NULL
C     2019-03-01      100         NULL             NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the data frame

```
data = [{'Amount':100,'3-month_Diff':-30},{'Amount':60,"3-month_Diff":-10}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And now to create you're new column `3-month_Diff%`. I'm going to leave it as a float instead of a string with the % marker at the end.

```
df['3-month_Diff%'] = df['3-month_Diff']/(df['Amount'] - df['3-month_Diff'])
```